# Monitor hardware on servers

Tags: windows, monitoring, hardware

In my company, we deliver hardware installations that all have a dedicated server (Windows Server 2008, 2012).

It's usually part of our customers' job to make sure the server stays healthy (by checking the disks' leds, UPS batteries and so on).

The problem is that they often forget to do it and, as an exemple, lately, we discovered a server, that for the past 2 months, had a raid 10 with 2 failed disks (out of 6 + one hot spare). It would be a disaster for our customer if the server went down and it would be our fault no matter what happened.

In order to prevent that, we would like to manage the hardware of the server and send messages to the customer and us when something fails so we could take the proper actions quickly.

On the server, we have a C# application that runs and our goal is to retrieve the different hardware status within our application to treat it properly.

**In summary, I would like to gather in my application, warnings, errors about :**

- RAID failures
- Hard disk failures
- Network cards problems
- Disc space getting low
- Other hardware

Is there a solution out of the box to get those informations ? An application that would gather those informations into the event viewer or logs would be nice too.

We tried :

- Dell Open Manage

We still need to try and get the information within our application. The downsides are that, it's manufacturer related and cannot gather all the informations (example -> UPS battery).

- IPMI / WMI

We had trouble seeing the disks. We were stuck at the RAID controller level. We had also different behavior on different servers generations.

Comment: glances can do a bit of what you want, and it is a free tool : https://github.com/nicolargo/glances but no logs management, and no reporting...

Comment: Monitoring the hardware and the OS? There are a bazillion tools for monitoring the server at the OS level (disk space utilization, event logs, etc.). What brand servers are these? What systems management tools does the manufacturer/vendor provide?

Comment: So you want to be an MSP that handles monitoring/alerting but have no idea if there is software out there that can do this?  Yeah, that sounded harsh...but honestly a quick google search would show you a ton of options, including ones specific to an MSP's needs.

Comment: Also, hardware support sucks.  You don't want to get into that business, so you need to be moving in the *other* direction, not in the direction towards monitoring and supporting every moron customer and their crappy environment.  "Here's your software, some recommendations and best practices.  If your server breaks, call Dell."

Comment: The hardware vendor may have command lines for that (I'm thinking of Dell OpenManage, etc.) that you can integrate into the monitoring of your choice.

Comment: Focus on the specific tools from the server manufacturer (such as HP Insight Remote Support, etc.)  Most will have some phone home functionality included that's going to cover some key things you haven't listed (power supplies, memory errors, fan speeds, etc.)  If you feel compelled to stay in the loop, set yourself up as an additional contact for the customer.

Comment: @joeqwerty We have Dell servers and Dell Open Manage installed but it forces us to connect and see what's happening. I would like to get the information from an application like Open Manage and gather them within my application. Furthermore, the UPS Battery is not listed in Dell Open Manage but has its own software. That means I now need discuss with two different application to get all the informations I need... Do you see what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Absolutely, see my answer above for more details... Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @BrandonXavier The thing is, I don't have an access to the server while it's at the customers. The end customers are within production and know nothing about computer science. To get stupid simple, they would like a red lamp blinking when something around the server goes wrong (memory, disks, and so on)...

Comment: @HopelessN00b Unfortunately, there are times when you cannot take other directions. I have to deal with a server, dropped in an environnement I don't have access to, with customers that don't know anything about them, and I need to simplify the monitoring of the computer through my application. If I COULD stay away from hardware support, believe me, I would.

Comment: That's the beauty of the manufacturer phone home functionality - a problem happens, the server notifies HP (for example), and the next thing I know a technician is calling me to schedule a service call.  Phone calls from technicians make for a good "red lamp blinking" ;-)

Comment: @BrandonXavier That's interesting. Since we're using DELL, I don't know if that's possible to have that. Do you know how the server notifies HP ? Sometimes, our servers are completely cut from outside the world... We thought adding a cellphone card and sending informations by sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of Dell OpenManage Server Administrator (DOMSA), Dell OpenManage Essentials (DOME) and SNMP you can configure the server to send hardware alerts to you via SNMP traps. This would necessitate your installing DOMSA and SNMP on the servers and configuring them to send SNMP alerts to a DOME instance that you would run at your location. It would also necessitate that you allow inbound SNMP from your customer to you through your firewall. This shouldn't require any configuration on the customer side. You can pre-configure the SNMP trap destination (s) on the servers before you ship them.

That gets you hardware layer monitoring. For OS layer monitoring you'll need to use some type of agent based monitoring solution that will allow you to monitor things like disk space utilization, etc. and that has the capability to generate and send alerts. I happen to use [Pulseway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsDPw.png) for this for my clients. It's inexpensive (something on the order of $1.34 USD per system per month). This gives you monitoring at the OS layer and gives you a cornucopia of remote monitoring information and management capabilities. Here's a snippet of the Pulseway control panel that I can use to remotely access and work with my remotely managed systems:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer ! You actually understood what we need. I'm also thinking that I need to stick with Dell Open Manage but I'm afraid to depend solely on a single Manufacturer. It's not impossible that, one day, a customer brings his own HP server. But, one step at a time, I'll dig your solution and see if that fits my needs. Thank you very much again !

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score -2):

I use PRTG for all the monitoring in our company. That and if you keep the number of sensors under 100, the program is free. It will monitor all you have listed.

Comment: Thank you but this appears to be really related to network right ?